# How to set property of button to visible from widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I have one window which includes all the buttons and there are some buttons that are hidden.

Now I want set visibility to true from another dialog.

How to do it?
I have googled it but I am unable to solve this problem.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "rams.h"
#include "abtdev.h"
#include "syllabus.h"
#include "login.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QMainWindow::showFullScreen();

    **ui->but_save->setHidden(true);
    ui->but_delete1->setHidden(true);
    ui->but_delete2->setHidden(true);
    ui->but_upload1->setHidden(true);
    ui->but_upload2->setHidden(true);**
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_but_abt_clicked()
{
    abtdev a;
    a.exec();
}

void MainWindow::on_but_Syllabus_clicked()
{
    syllabus s;
    s.showFullScreen();
    s.exec();
}

void MainWindow::on_but_admin_clicked()
{
    login objlogin;
    objlogin.exec();
}

void MainWindow::on_but_rams_clicked()
{
    // rams ramswin;
    // ramswin.showFullScreen();
    // ramswin.exec();
}
```

And I want it appear after this dialog box get completed!

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"
#include<QTimer>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QObject>

login::login(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QTimer::singleShot(60000, this, SLOT(close()));
    ui->password->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}

void login::on_ok_clicked()
{
    QString username = ui->username->text();
        QString password = ui->password->text();

        if(username ==  "123" && password == "123")
        {


       ***HERE, after this block executed i want that buttons visible on mainwindow***

          }
        else
        {
            ui->label_4->setText("Username and password is not correct !!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Use signals and slots from the dialog to the window and then use method hide(false) on the button.

Comment: how sir , i am new in qt ,please tell me

Comment: As a head start you can take a look at my Tutorial/Example on how to exchange signals and slot between windows in Qt here on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/2136/signals-and-slots/26119/multi-window-signal-slot-connection#t=201701131949329521175

Comment: Or on GitHub so you can fork it and add code to it: https://github.com/LucaAngioloni/QTMultiwindowExample

Comment: Then in the mainwindow slot you can write the code to show the buttons (i.e. the method `setHidden(false)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you need is next:

Supposing that you call your dialog for example from `MainWindow::on_but_admin_clicked()` function:

On **mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_but_admin_clicked()
{
    //Declare a private object in your mainwindow.h like this:
    //login* objlogin; 
    objlogin = new login();
    //Connect signals to later call the method setHiden(false)
    QObject::connect(objlogin, SIGNAL(stackoverflowAnswer()), this, SLOT(makeVisible()));
    objlogin->show();
}

//...
// The function that will be called from login dialog to enable hidden buttons
void MainWindow::makeVisible()
{
    ui->but_save->setHidden(false);
    ui->but_delete1->setHidden(false);
    ui->but_delete2->setHidden(false);
    ui->but_upload1->setHidden(false);
    ui->but_upload2->setHidden(false);
}
```

On **login.cpp** *(on_ok_clicked() function)*:

```
void login::on_ok_clicked()
{
    QString username = ui->username->text();
        QString password = ui->password->text();

        if(username ==  "123" && password == "123")
        {


       ***HERE, after this block executed i want that buttons visible on mainwindow***

            emit stackoverflowAnswer();
            //...
```

Remember to declare in **login.h** the signals and slots:

```
signals:
    void stackoverflowAnswer();
private slots:
    void on_ok_clicked();
```